# "The configuration registry database is corrupt" when putting in "netsh http show ssl" on administrator command prompt

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, ssl

I've been trying to fix this error:

```
An error occurred while using SSL configuration for endpoint Type=0 Index=0. The error status code is contained within the returned data. (Event 15021)
```

From the Event Viewer as my PC keeps freezing (sometimes) after startup or wake from sleep.

I read online to check my ssl certificates, so I did "netsh http show ssl", however, it showed me

```
SSL Certificate bindings:

-------------------------

The configuration registry database is corrupt.
```

I've been trying to fix it all day, and I already did sfc /scannow and DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth, (and /scanhealth) which claimed to fix some corrupt files, but the issue still remains. If anyone knows how I can fix this, it would be deeply appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: SFC and DISM are not good problem fixers. I suggest to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Windows Server 2016 running IIS 10. Running `netsh show ssl cert` showed a corrupted configuration database. I couldn't start IIS since this issue also kept the HTTP service from loading.

I was able to clear out the bad mapping by running regedit and going to:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\SslBindingInfo
```

and deleting the subkeys for the bad mapping. For me it was `0.0.0.0:443`, but it could be another one depending on what bindings you have on your machine.